# Migrate Redis Data To Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-server, redis-cluster

We have a single Redis instance with a good amount of data (over 100GB). We also have an empty Redis Cluster with 6 nodes. What would be the best way to move all that data from the stand-alone instance to the Redis Cluster and make it distribute it evenly?

Comment: "and make it distribute it evenly" You can't do that as the keyspace is  not guaranteed to be evenly distributed.

Comment: You're right. In this case splitting up the nodes into equal number of slots would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching around, I came across a post detailing how to move data over to a cluster. It may take some time to move lots of data over but this is the best way I've seen so far.

You can read about it here: https://fnordig.de/2014/03/11/redis-cluster-with-pre-existing-data/

Comment: Yeah that's the best I've found so far as well, but redis-trib.rb is no longer available in redis version 5. My test cluster gets stuck while resharding slots from instance 1 to instance 2

Moving slot 1186 from 127.0.0.1:30001 to 127.0.0.1:30002: 
ERR Target instance replied with error: CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down

Answer (score 0):

You could make it easier by using [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) and a cluster proxy programm like [redis-cerberus](https://github.com/HunanTV/redis-cerberus) after you dump data into an RDB file

```
rdb --command protocol RDB_FILE_PATH | nc PROXY_HOST PROXY_PORT
```

Piping an AOF file into a proxy *maybe doesn't work* somehow if the AOF file contains cross-slots commands like `RPOPLPUSH` (depending on the proxy's implementation). However if you are actually using this kind of commands, you are not supposed to use a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RedisShake](https://github.com/tair-opensource/RedisShake) to migrate your Redis data to a cluster:

shake.toml:

```ini
[sync_reader]
address = "127.0.0.1:6379"

[redis_writer]
cluster = true
address = "127.0.0.1:6380"
```

Start RedisShake by running the following command:

```bash
./redis-shake shake.toml
```

I hope this helps!